# CSS background-attachment: fixed doesn't work properly on floated elements

Tags: css, css-position

When I set `background-attachment: fixed` as a property for a group of floated elements, `background-position` doesn't work properly. If I set the value normally to '`left top`', it positions properly only left column of elements. If I set it to '`center`', only the images in cental columns are visible, etc. Only way to set it to behave properly is to add image's offset to `background-position-x`, or to increase `background-size`, but I don't want that. Any ideas?

Here is my CSS:

```
.element {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: initial;
    background-image: url(...);
}
```

Comment: That is indeed a problem. I was able to work around it with a nasty trick, however. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n7x0bLhh/ Would that work?

Comment: Looks like it would, if the nasty trick is to leave background-repeat as repeat. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, I've posted it an an answer. Maybe you can work with that until something better comes up.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is to set the background-repeat to `repeat` and to make the background image exactly as large as the floating element plus its margins.

```css
.element {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: initial;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/320/320/animals/5);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">div 1</div>
<div class="element">div 2</div>
<div class="element">div 3</div>
<div class="element">div 4</div>
<div class="element">div 5</div>
<div class="element">div 6</div>
<div class="element">div 7</div>
```

The drawback of this method is that it has a number of restrictions:

- The elements must all be the same size and have the same margin
- The background image must be that size as well
- All the elements get the very same background

If that works, OK! Otherwise, I'd be thrilled to see if this question gets a better answer.

Comment: For the moment this is the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the element in a "clearfix" class:

**CSS:**

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

More clearfix information [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

"A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear its child elements, so that you don't need to add additional markup. It's generally used in float layouts where elements are floated to be stacked horizontally. The clearfix is a way to combat the zero-height container problem for floated elements." [Dec 18, 2011 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

You could also wrap your element inside of a float:

**CSS:**

```
.element-wrap {
    float: left;
}
.element {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: initial;
    background-image: url(...);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="element-wrap">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried wrapping floated elements with clearfix elements with such styles, but that doesn't change anything about background image position issue. How is it related anyway?

Comment: How about a wrapper of float? See new answer.

Comment: At least in my case, clearing content:after or wrapping it with another floated element doesn't change background image behaviour. I still don't see how it could be related.